# Is it possible to create a pytest fixture for class-instance scope?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Let's suppose I have multiple sets of parameters:

```
[
  ('a', 'b'),
  ('c', 'd'),
  ('e', 'f')
]
```

This set of parameters is not static. It is fetched from another function.

So in my case it is pretty handy to parametrize a class with this set of parameters:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('a, b', [
  ('a', 'b'),
  ('c', 'd'),
  ('e', 'f')
])
class TestClass:
def test_a(self, a, b):
    print(a)
def test_b(self, a, b):
    print(b)
```

But I also have cases where I need to calculate some third value `c` based on these values `a` and `b`.
The calculation of the value `c` is pretty time-consuming task, so I would like to move it to a fixture (something like this):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('a, b', [
      ('a', 'b'),
      ('c', 'd'),
      ('e', 'f')
])
class TestClass:
    @pytest.fixture
    def calculate_c(a, b):
        return a + b

    def test_a(self, a, b, calculate_c):
        print(a)

    def test_b(self, a, b, calculate_c):
        print(b)
```

It is obvious that the result of the function `calculate_c` will be different for every set of parameters.

I know that there is a `scope="class"` in pytest, but according to my experiments, this is not what I need.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: so you want `calculate_c` to happen once when fixtures are loaded? how would this be possible if the parameters to the fixture change?

Comment: @aws_apprentice I want `calculate_c` to do the "calculations" only once per set or parameters.
So in my example I want `calculate_c` to be executed 3 times with 3 pairs of parameters: `[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]`
I think this should be possible since parameters `a` and `b` are passed inside a class and `calculate_c` is calculated based on these parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. Of course, if the size of c is large, and the number of parameters is high, you might start paying a noticeable memory cost to store them all. Unfortunately, you can't get away with storing only one at a time, because pytest runs test_a with every parameter pair before moving on to test_b.

import pytest

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('a, b', [
      ('a', 'b'),
      ('c', 'd'),
      ('e', 'f')
])
class TestClass:

    @classmethod
    def calculate_c(self, a, b):
        try:
            if self.c_map[(a,b)]:
                print("didn't calculate")
                return self.c_map[(a,b)]
        except AttributeError:
            self.c_map = {}
        except KeyError:
            pass

        self.c_map[(a, b)] = a+b # do whatever expensive computation here                                                                                  
        return self.c_map[(a,b)]


    def test_a(self, a, b):
        c = self.calculate_c(a, b)
        print(a, c)

    def test_b(self, a, b):
        c = self.calculate_c(a, b)
        print(b, c)
```

produces:

```
a ab
.c cd
.e ef
.didn't calculate
b ab
.didn't calculate
d cd
.didn't calculate
f ef
.
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!
Also, the explanation of pytest tests sequence helped me understand why this is not possible to do natively using pytest fixtures.

Comment: One more idea came to my mind – instead of writing saving mechanism of `calculate_c` by myself it is possible to use `functools.lru_cache` decorator.